# How to I work with dictionary's (Markov chains) that are too big for ram?

Tags: python, markov-chains

I'm working on a Markov chain text generator in python training of a large corpus 20 GB+. It takes plain text and splits it into pairs, the current two words selected and the word that follows. This is part of the list:

```
[(('as', 'a'), 'subject'), (('a', 'subject'), 'for'), (('subject', 'for'), 'the'), (('for', 'the'), 'remarks'), (('the', 'remarks'), 'of'), (('remarks', 'of'), 'the'), (('of', 'the'), 'evening'), (('the', 'evening'), 'the'), (('evening', 'the'), 'perpetuation'), (('the', 'perpetuation'), 'of'), (('perpetuation', 'of'), 'our'), (('of', 'our'), 'political')]
```

I then put this into a dictionary so if I have a key (two words) that occur multiple times I can just put the value as an array with multiple values:

```
{('as', 'a'): ['subject', 'nation'], ('a', 'subject'): ['for'], ('subject', 'for'): ['the'], ('for', 'the'): ['remarks', 'executive', 'government', 'laws', 'redress', 'sake', 'constitution'], ('the', 'remarks'): ['of']}
```

I do this again for thousands of files adding to that dictionary, after a while it is too big for ram. Is there a way to store such a dictionary on disk?
The data structure:

- needs to be fast
- editable once made
- easily searchable

I the best ideas I have had is a database or csv file but I read they are impractical.

Comment: If you did have enough memory, what would you do after training? Do you plan on storing? Fast is relative. A database would seem like a good compromise. Use Python's [builtin support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for [tag:sqlite] and see whether it's fast enough for you.

Comment: I would use it to generate sentences I start with two words and find the values that mach that key. Say start with (I, Went) the values I get back are [to, back, around], I pick one and add it to the sentence which would now be (I, Went, back). I keep doing the same thing (Went, back) -> [To,Home,For, Gasping]. I will always keep it on the disk so I don't need to re-train, but I need it to be fast in the sense I give it a key and it can quickly return the list of values as I will have to do this a hundred times over.